# Variable scope in Javascript for loop

Tags: javascript

What's the difference between:

```
function bar()
{
  for (x=0; x< 100; x++) {}
}
```

And

```
function bar()
{
  var x;
  for (x=0; x< 100; x++) {}
}
```

If x wasn't declared outside of that function, and so it wasn't a global variable? I always wonder this because I generally don't declare throwaway variables which are used only in a loop, but I wonder if this might break comparability in a browser or such.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The first example will either add or modify the global variable x, which is generally to be avoided if not the desired outcome.

While your second example works as desired (no side effects) an alternative that looks better in my opinion would be

```
function bar()
{
  for (var x=0; x< 100; x++) {}
}
```

Comment: Any variable not declared with "var" will always be a global variable.  Here's the MDC entry on var: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/Var

Comment: It may look better, but JavaScript has no block scope, hence it's no matter if you declare `x` inside or outside the `for` loop. (JS 1.7 introduce the `let` keyword, see noha's answer.)

Comment: +1 for always add the var.  I've seen many cases where one loop using 'i' calls a function with its own loop using 'i' where both update a global 'i'.  It may go unnoticed in some cases but completely mess things up in others.

Answer (score 16):

A variable is created at the time you declare/use it. If you omit the var keyword than the variable is created automatically in the global scope. So you produce a side effect. This is generally to be avoided.

Assume you use global variables and then you chose the name of variable that some other piece of the software has already taken. This will lead to a situation where to pieces of code overwrite their values. This produces errors and is most of the time hard to debug. In your example you might overwriting a global variable x that another software is using.

Using var is also faster. If you access a global variable it has to scan all scopes up to the global one for the variable name. By using var it is bound to your local scope.

It is good practice to use always use var. Or better: it is always good to select the most narrowed scope for your variables. Now you have global and var. A var declaration is visible in the whole function no matter where you declare it. In javascript 1.7 there is new keyword introduced: let. Let narrows the scope even more. If you declare your for loop with

```
for(let x = 0; x < 100; i++) {}
```

than x is visible only inside the {} block.

Comment: Is 1.7 on most browsers now?

Answer (score 2):

Always remember, in JavaScript, scopes are defined by functions.
In the example

```
function () {
    var x = 15;
    bar();
    function bar() {
      for (x=0; x< 100; x++) {}
    }
    //here x will be 100
}
```

You might accidentally access a higher scope. What I mean of higher scope is a wrapper function or window.x (if no more wrapper function is there). It's much better to stick to the second example if you just want to use x for your loop.

```
function () {
    var x = 15;
    bar();
    function bar() {
        var x;
        for (x=0; x< 100; x++) {}
    }
    //here x will be 15
}
```