# Do I need to declare the iterator inside a for loop?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Variable scope in Javascript for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790558/variable-scope-in-javascript-for-loop)

```
for(i=0;i<4;i++){

}
```

Do I need to say:

`for(var i=0;i<4;i++)` ...?

Otherwise things will be global, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't need to declare the iterator variable inside a loop. This is also perfectly valid -

```
var i;

for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    alert(i);
```

An [example](http://jsfiddle.net/JGSmv/) on jsfiddle.

You may also want to see [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#Variable_Scope) section about variable scope and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope) page about function scope on MDN.

Comment: The reason for declaring within the for statement is that this scopes it to the statement. Unless you want it outside the statement, that is ideal. If you need it outside the for statement then you have to use Sayems approach.

Comment: @SchroedingersCat: JavaScript does not have block scope. No matter where you declare it, the variable will be accessible throughout the function.

Comment: @jon then I take it back. I tend to do things in js like I do them in c#, so I don't get too confused, and assume that some of the reasons are the same.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. If you don't declare the variable in the for loop, then it would assume that you are referring to some variable "i", which was declared before. If the variable is not declared already then you would get an error. It is best to declare the iterator in the for loop.

Answer (score -1):

Without `var`

```
m-racoon:~ mkotsur$ node
> function test() {
... for(i=0;i<4;i++){
... console.log(i);
... }
... }
> test();
0
1
2
3
> console.log(i);
4
```

With `var`

```
> function test1() {
... for(var j=0;j<4;j++){
... console.log(j);
... }
... }
> test1()
0
1
2
3
> console.log(j);
ReferenceError: j is not defined
```

So, answer: Yes.